# PostgreSql Table partitioning and max number of partitions and management

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

If I only do equality comparisons on my partition check constraints in PostgreSql will this then hurt the query planning performance as much as if I did range partitioning.

I have some large tables i would like to partition by a integer `TenantId` should i still aim for only having around 100 tenants in each database?

Also how do people manage the tables generated by partitioning. Should i throw them into a seperate schema? or just have to accept that im going to be scrolling through 100+ tables of DataTenant001, DataTenant002, DataTenant003 when browsing the database?